# Ecto association to more than one schemas

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Assuming

```
schema "infrastructure_instances" do
  belongs_to :provider, MyApp.Infrastructure.Provider
  belongs_to :user, MyApp.Web.User
end
```

and

```
schema "infrastructure_providers" do
  belongs_to :user, MyApp.Web.User
  has_many :instances, MyApp.Infrastructure.Instance
end
```

... and

```
schema "account_users" do
  has_many :providers, MyApp.Infrastructure.Provider
  has_many :instances, MyApp.Infrastructure.Instance
end
```

How would i build an association for an Instance to a Provider and a User

This works, but there should certainly be a better way,

```
def create_instance(attrs \\ %{},user) do
  user
  |> build_assoc(:instances,provider_id: provider_id)
```

Thank You

Comment: I'd probably just do `%Instance{provider_id: provider.id, user_id: user.id}` here for clarity.

Comment: @Dogbert, Yet another possible way of dong this. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
build_assoc(user, :instances, provider: provider)
```

(hopefully it works this way) or

```
build_assoc(user, :instances, provider_id: provider_id)
```

seems fine to me. So your way is not that bad I think.

Or maybe this if you need to create a changeset ->

```
%Instance{}
|> Changeset.change()
|> Changeset.put_assoc(:user, user_struct_or_changeset)
|> Changeset.put_assoc(:provider, provider_struct_or_changeset)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Was looking at passing Map.from_struct to build_assoc/3 ?